# If $f$ is holomorphic and $\,f'' = f$, then $f(z) = A \cosh z + B \sinh z$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, analyticity, hyperbolic-functions

Suppose $f$ is holomorphic in a disk centered at the origin and $f$ satisfies the differential equation $$f'' = f.$$ Show that $f$ is of the form $$f(z)=A \sinh z + B \cosh z,$$ for suitable constants $A,B\in \mathbb C$.

---

Of course if $f$ were a function of one real variable, usual techniques to solve linear homogeneous differential equations ([characteristic equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_equation_(calculus)) and so on) would quickly solve the problem. But using the same train of thought here, $f$ is a function of *two* real variables ($z = x + iy$), and so the same techniques cannot be applied directly. This is really a complex analysis problem.

Comment: It might be easier to show that $f(z)=Ce^z + De^{-z}$ for some $C,D$, then use the formula for $\cosh$ and $\sinh$ to figure out what $A,B$ should be.

Comment: Is this in a differential equation course?  Then perhaps there are some "existence and uniqueness" theorems.  Was there a similar worked-out example, say the D.E. $f'' = -f$ just before this?

Comment: This is a complex analysis course. Unfortunately, there has been no mention of ODE's before this problem (it was taken from a different book).

Comment: Why can this not be trivially done by recognizing that $f(z) = A\cosh{z} + B \sinh{z}$ is the general solution to the differential equation $y'' - y = 0$?

Comment: Is it possible that this might have something to do with analytic continuation?

Comment: By existence and uniqueness of solutions of ODE, $A$ and $B$ are constants determined by initial conditions. If $f$ satisfies the ODE in the disc $D_\epsilon(0)$, then it has to equal $A\cosh z+B\sinh z$ for some $A,B$. Hence by analytic continuation. $f$ is entire.

Answer (score 19):

We shall use a method identical to the one used for ODEs with a real variable, namely, integration after multiplying with a suitable *integrating factor*. As the equation is second order, we first rewrite the equation in a way that allows us to integrate it.

Adding $\,\,f'$ on both sides of the equation we obtain
$$f''+f'=f'+f.$$ Thus setting $\,g=f+f'$, we get that $g'=g$, and hence
multiplying by the integrating factor $\,\mathrm{e}^{-z}$ we obtain
$$
0=\mathrm{e}^{-z}\big(g'(z)-g(z)\big)=\big(\mathrm{e}^{-z}g(z)\big)',
$$
which implies that $\mathrm{e}^{-z}g(z)$ is a constant analytic function (given that the domain of $f$ is open and connected), i.e., $\,g(z)=c\,\mathrm{e}^{z}$, for some $c\in\mathbb C$. 
Consequently
$$
f'(z)+f(z)=c\,\mathrm{e}^{z},
$$
which when multiplied by $\mathrm{e}^{z}$ provides that
$$
\mathrm{e}^{z}\big(f'(z)+f(z)\big)=c\,\mathrm{e}^{2z},
$$
or
$$
\big(\mathrm{e}^{z}f(z)\big)'
=c\,\mathrm{e}^{2z}
=\frac{c}{2}\big(\mathrm{e}^{2z}\big)',
$$
and hence
$$
\mathrm{e}^{z}f(z)=\frac{c}{2}\mathrm{e}^{2z}+c',
$$
for some $c'\in\mathbb C$, or
$$
f(z)=\frac{c}{2}\mathrm{e}^{z}+c'\mathrm{e}^{-z}=a\cosh z+b\sinh z,
$$
where
$a+b=c \quad\text{and}\quad a-b=2c'.$

Conversely, every function of the form
$$
f(z)=a\cosh z+b\sinh z,\quad a,b\in\mathbb C,
$$
satisfies the equation $f''=f$.

Comment: Very nice, thanks for the detailed explanation. I think I was missing the key observation that, setting $g = f + f'$ yields $g' = g$.

Answer (score 5):

Let : $$g=f-f(0)\cosh-f'(0)\sinh$$

This function is holomorphic in the same disc $D=D(0,r)$ as $f$.

You clearly have $g(0)=g'(0)=0$ and $g''=g$, so by induction $g^{(k)}(0)=0$ for all $k\geqslant 0$, and consequently
$$g(z)=\sum_{k\geqslant 0} \frac{g^{(k)}(0)}{k!}z^k=0$$

for all $z$ in a disc $D(0,r')$ with $0<r'\leqslant r$.

Hence $g=0$ on the domain $D$, i.e. $f=f(0)\cosh+f'(0)\sinh$ on $D$.

Answer (score 3):

You can always turn a linear homogeneous differential equation with constant coefficients (such as the one you are asking about) into a linear system. Here, you have $f''-f=0$, so if we set $v=\begin{pmatrix}f\\ f'\end{pmatrix}$, we have that $v'=\begin{pmatrix}f'\\f''\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}f'\\ f\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}v$.

The point of this is that you reduce solving the equation to pure linear algebra. First, call $A=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}$, and note that we can diagonalize it as $A=S\Lambda S^{-1}$, where $S=\begin{pmatrix}-1&1\\1&1\end{pmatrix}$ and $\Lambda=\begin{pmatrix}-1&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$. (Note that the first column of $A$ is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $-1$, and the second is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $1$.)

The reason why we do this is that $S\Lambda S^{-1}v=v'$ iff $\Lambda S^{-1}v=S^{-1}v'=(S^{-1}v)'$ so that, letting $w=S^{-1}v$, we have that the original equation is equivalent to $\Lambda w=w'$. Now, if $w=\begin{pmatrix}g\\ h\end{pmatrix}$, then this is saying that $g'=-g$, and $h'=h$, so that $g(x)=ae^{-x}$ and $h(x)=be^{x}$ for some constants $a,b$. Since $\begin{pmatrix}f\\f'\end{pmatrix}=v=Sw$, it follows that $f$ is a linear combination of $e^x$ and $e^{-x}$.

---

The approach is perfectly general, and just as easy as long as the resulting $A$ is diagonalizable. If $A$ is not diagonalizable (which for the matrices we get here,  happens precisely when $A$ has repeated eigenvalues), we can still solve the system this way, using now the Jordan form of $A$. Yiorgos's solution can be easily seen to be equivalent to what we are doing here. A nice book explaining all of this is volume II of Apostol's *Calculus*.

Let me briefly explain the connection. Note first that $A^2-I=0$, and $p(x)=x^2-1$ is the smallest non-zero (monic) polynomial that vanishes when applied to $A$ (it is the *minimal* polynomial of $A$). This is just the characteristic polynomial of $A$. In fact, given any linear homogeneous differential equation with constant coefficients, rewriting it as a system $Av=v'$ always results in an $A$ whose minimal polynomial is also the characteristic polynomial, and is just the characteristic polynomial of the equation: If we want to solve $f^{(n)}-a_{n-1}f^{(n-1)}-\dots-a_0f=0$, this equation polynomial equation is $x^n-a_{n-1}x^{n-1}-\dots-a_0$. This shows that the eigenvalues of $A$ (the roots of $p$) are closely related to the solutions of the differential equation.

To make the relation more transparent, write $D$ for the derivative operator: $Df=f'$. Then the equation is just $(D^n-a_{n-1}D^{n-1}-\dots-a_0I)f=0$, where $I$ is the identity operator, $If=f$. To solve this, we factor the polynomial in $D$, and solve. For example, starting with $f''-f=0$, we get $(D^2-I)f=0$, or $(D-I)(D+I)f=0$, so if $g=(D+I)f$, then $(D-I)g=0$, or $g'=g$, or $g=ae^x$. Then we need to solve $(D+I)f=g$, or $f'+f=ae^x$, so $f=be^{-x}+ce^x$.

In general, if the resulting polynomial has degree $n$ and $n$ different roots $\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n$, the procedure just sketched gives us that the solution has the form $b_1e^{\lambda_1 x}+\dots+b_ne^{\lambda_n x}$ for some constants $\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n$. The case where the roots are repeated is slightly more involved, and instead of constants, the $b_i$ are now polynomials in $x$ ($b_i$ of degree $k_i-1$ if $\lambda_i$ appears as a root $k_i$ times). This can either be proved directly, and then used to deduce the general form of the Jordan form of $A$, or can be proved starting with the Jordan form of $A$.

Answer (score 1):

Standard operator factoring
$$
        e^{z}\frac{d}{dz}\left[e^{-2z}\frac{d}{dz}(e^{z}f)\right]=f''-f.
$$

Comment: Yes! ... btw, did you want $f'' - f$, there appears to be some typo

Comment: @orangeskid : Thank you! I fixed that typo now.