# $f'(x) = c \cdot f(x)$ when $f$ is complex valued

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $c\in\mathbb{C}$.
I would like to solve $\forall x\in\mathbb{R} f'(x) = c \cdot f(x)$ and $f(0)=1$ for $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$.

If $c$ was real and $f$ was a real function, I would get the well known $f(x)=e^{cx}$. I am not sure how to extend it to this case.

Just to clarify: I am interested in finding all solutions.

Comment: Perhaps related (but not duplicate): https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/679749/if-f-is-holomorphic-and-f-f-then-fz-a-cosh-z-b-sinh-z

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's just like the real case. If $f' = cf$, then you can check that $e^{-cx} f(x)$ has derivative zero everywhere, thus it's constant. You can find this constant to be $1$ because of $f(0)=1$.

Comment: @JoLasker You're right. Indeed I had $z \in \mathbb C$ in mind (the proof stays the same). I changed it to $x$.